# How to detect word before ":" and wrap in "span" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I'm trying to detect a character in a text, and if found wrap the word before it in a HTML element, and remove that character.

**Example:**

```
Case:
```

becomes

```
<span class="th">Case</span>
```

**Method**

I can detect the presence of `:` using:

```
if (str.indexOf(':') > -1)
```

To get the word before I'm using:

```
var th = str.split(':')[0];
```

To wrap the word in an element I tried:

```
var th_wrap = "<span class='th'></span>";  
$(th).wrap(th_wrap);
```

Which doesn't work. 
To remove the `:` I tried:

```
th.replace(':', '');
```

Which also doesn't work.

To make it slightly more complicated, I want to catch any occurance of `someword:`, not just the first one.

I'd appreciate any pointers, cheers. (javascript or jQuery)

**SNIPPET**

```js
var str = $('.target').html();
if (str.indexOf(':') > -1) {
  var th = str.split(':')[0];
  th.replace(':', '');
  var th_wrap = "<span class='th'></span>";
  $(th).wrap(th_wrap);
}
```

```css
th { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="target">
  Case 1:
  <br />some text
  <br />some more text
  <br />even more text
  <br />
  <br />Case 2:
  <br />some text
  <br />some more text
  <br />even more text
</p>
```

Comment: th has to be a DOM element. not a string.
If you ar trying to replace the first case with your desired `<span>`, it's better to get the first child of `.target` and replace it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the words ***Case 1:*** and ***Case 2:*** are text nodes.

So, you need to get all nodes under ***target***: for this, use [jQuery.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/).

The snippet:

```js
$('.target').contents().each(function(idx, ele) {
  if (ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE &&
            ele.textContent.indexOf(':') > -1) {
    ele.textContent = ele.textContent.replace(':', '');
    $(ele).wrap($('<span/>', {
      class: 'th'
    }));

  }
});
```

```css
.th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="target">
    Case 1:
    <br />some text
    <br />some more text
    <br />even more text
    <br />
    <br />Case 2:
    <br />some text
    <br />some more text
    <br />even more text
</p>
```

Comment: How does this code know what to wrap before the ':' ? For example, 'Case 2' - why does it not also wrap the words before 'Case'?

Comment: Because before"Case 2" there is a tag (br). If, instead your format changes you may always use regex. In any case this approach gives you the possibility to act only on textNode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to do this work. Use jquery [`.html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to change html of p. In function of callback use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to wrap target string in span.

```js
$("p").html(function(i, html){
  return html.replace(/(\w+\s\d+):/g, "<span class='th'>$1</span>");
});
```

```css
.th { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="target">
  Case 1:
  <br />some text
  <br />some more text
  <br />even more text
  <br />
  <br />Case 2:
  <br />some text
  <br />some more text
  <br />even more text
</p>
```

Comment: @ovokuro Yes, see https://jsfiddle.net/06oe5gn3/ .It work if br or any other element  exist or doesn't exist in p.

Comment: Thanks. If a situation happens where another word exists before 'case' then it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/xpwbdzqg/1/   --- your solution is good for me if there is no br, but the other solution is better if there are extra words! I will have to find a compromise. Thanks for your help